# How to bundle resources for a static library for UWP platform?

Tags: cmake, uwp, resourcebundle

I need to build a graphics-related static library which has some reosurces like images and shaders files, and this library will be used by an UWP app. But the problem with static library is in distributing its resource files.

Is there a way to create a resource bundle in Visual Studio for static library (like XCode provides .bundle for iOS and MacOSX), which can be given to client along with static library and its header files?

A follow up question, can we create such resource bundles them using CMake?

Comment: Never know that UWP has this kind of mechanism. Normally UWP use URI  to load the resource https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.foundation.uri.  Have you included your .res file in your project? What's the error you get? Unlike XCode, in Xcode the .bundle works like the uri. But in UWP it is different.

Comment: Hi Barry, the uwp app doesn't require those resources by itself, those are required just by static library, which then will be used by UWP app. My question is around: how can we give any client app, the resources of a static library along with .lib library?
For Apple platform, we generally provide the static library (.a file) and its resources as .bundle to the client. Similarly, how can we achieve this for UWP.

Comment: @vivek2k6 using a NuGet package,